# Why is the author using global variables in this code?

Tags: python, global-variables

I'm trying to follow [this](https://www.giacomodebidda.com/posts/mvc-pattern-in-python-introduction-and-basicmodel/) tutorial on building a basic MVC in python. The tutorial starts with the following:

```
items = list()

def create_items(app_items):
  global items
  items = app_items

def create_item(name, price, quantity):
  global items
  items.append(
    {
      "name": name,
      "price": price,
      "quantity": quantity
    }
  )
```

I added the following main block at the bottom of the script to test out the functionality:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
  create_item("a", 1, 2)
  print(items)
```

Does anyone else here find it strange that `items` is declared `global` inside each function? This doesn't seem necessary (or pythonic) at all to me. variables declared outside of function scope are `global` by default in python, such that the following:

```
items = list()

def create_items(app_items):
  items = app_items

def create_item(name, price, quantity):
  items.append(
    {
      "name": name,
      "price": price,
      "quantity": quantity
    }
  )

if __name__=="__main__":
  create_item("a", 1, 2)
  print(items)
```

Will result in the same output. Does anyone else find it strange as well? Did the author maybe have any good reasons to do this?

Comment: Try using your modified `create_items`, and you'll find your understanding of `global` is wrong.

Comment: It will throw UnboundLocalError.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Running my modified `create_items` returns the exact same result  as the one in the blog and throws no error. I'm not sure what you are referring to?

Comment: If you remove global in function declaration python will create on more variable with the same name in local - function scope. `Global` var_name means this variable belongs to the global scope. To be more confused there is another keyword `nonlocal` variable. :)

Comment: The author does mention this : 

`Keep in mind that we have to use a global variable to store the list of items because its state must be shared across all operations`

Comment: @user32882: [Does this look like the correct output to you?](https://ideone.com/Rox2ca)

Comment: Your modified example isn't equivalent, but to be honest that use of global makes me think it's just a poorly designed tutorial.

Comment: @user32882, both snippets in your code never use `create_items()` (note the plural). i.e. you never test the difference based on these snippets. That said, given the examples, `global` is necessary in `create_items()` and not necessary in `create_item()` because list is mutable object. All that said I agree with @BrenBarn that using global is red flag for the tutorial.

Comment: @buran I'd argue that the function `create_items()` is not even necessary here. `items` is already global...

Comment: @user32882, I didn't look at the whole tutorial, but I guess the idea is to allow to pass/bind arbitrary list to `items`. Although, when in global scope you can directly bind  an object to `items` and you are correct it is redundant - one more red flag...

Comment: @KellyBundy: Looking at the tutorial, I'm not so sure.  Later when they define the model class, it imports `basic_backend` and uses the functions from there, which are the ones using globals.  So it doesn't look like it ever actually removes the reliance on globals.

Comment: @BrenBarn Yes, sorry, didn't see the connection, already deleted my comment. Still not convinced it's really bad, though, might make sense to do it this way in the tutorial, but I'd have to read it fully...

Comment: @buran I think you're right about it being a poor quality tutorial. It claims to describe the MVC but I now see key aspects of a true MVC missing, such as the ability to attach and/or detach a View to a Model. I'm dropping it.

Answer (score -1):

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

> Assignment of an object to a single target is recursively defined as follows.
>
> - If the target is an identifier (name):
>
>   - If the name does not occur in a `global` or `nonlocal` statement in the current code block: the name is bound to the object in the current local namespace.
>   - Otherwise: the name is bound to the object in the global namespace or the outer namespace determined by `nonlocal`, respectively.

### Function `create_items()`

```
def create_items(app_items):
    items = app_items
```

This function performs an *assignment* (using the `=` operator), so the quoted text applies:

- The name `items` does not appear in a `global` statement (it does in the original version!)
- So, the name `items` is bound to the "object in the current local namespace"

Or, in other words:

- A local variable is created (current local namespace: function)
- The name `items` is bound to it
- The value of `app_items` is assigned to the *local* variable `items`

### Function `create_item()`

```
def create_item(name, price, quantity):
    items.append(...)
```

This function does *not* perform an assignment, so the `global` statement isn't required here.